# Cannot use ActivityOptionsCompat in onClick() method

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener

i am trying to make shareable transition from one activity to another 
this is my main activity code

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=21){
        TransitionInflater ti=TransitionInflater.from(this);
        Transition t=ti.inflateTransition(R.transition.transition);
        getWindow().setEnterTransition(t);
        getWindow().setExitTransition(t);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b=(Button)  findViewById(R.id.button);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            view.setTransitionName("test");
            ActivityOptionsCompat c=ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,view.getTransitionName());
        }
    });
}
```

and second activity code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=21){

        Transition i=TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.transition);
        getWindow().setEnterTransition(i);
        getWindow().setExitTransition(i);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.b);

}
```

i am getting error

```
 error: incompatible types: <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Activity
            ActivityOptionsCompat c=ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,view.getTransitionName());
```

enabled current window transtions in style.xml

```
 <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
```

and did create transation xml file in res folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<slide/>
<changeBounds/>
</transitionSet>
```

in all tutorials it works but when i try its not working
why is it happening and what is the fix for it

and error it shows is

```
Wrong 2nd argument type.ound:'java.lang.String',required:android.support.v4.util.Pair<android.view.View,java.lang.String>makeSceneTransitionAnimation(Activity,android.support.v4.util.Pair<android.view.View,java.lang.String>...)in ActivityOptionsCompat cannot be applied to (MainActivity,java.lang.String)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

```
ActivityOptionsCompat c = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,view.getTransitionName());
```

to

```
ActivityOptionsCompat c = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(YOUR_ACTIVITY.this,view.getTransitionName());
```

For instance `MainActivity.this`

UPD

Look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityOptionsCompat.html#makeSceneTransitionAnimation(android.app.Activity,%20android.view.View,%20java.lang.String)), the `makeSceneTransitionAnimation` should be like this:

> makeSceneTransitionAnimation (Activity activity, 
>                   View sharedElement, 
>                   String sharedElementName)

Comment: Not the same result, you posted another error. You missed the second argument at the `makeSceneTransitionAnimation` method. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityOptionsCompat.html#makeSceneTransitionAnimation(android.app.Activity, android.view.View, java.lang.String)

Comment: if you can suggest any other work around for Shared elements transitions

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
ActivityOptionsCompat c=ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,view.getTransitionName());
```

to

```
ActivityOptionsCompat c=ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(),view.getTransitionName());
```

Comment: cannot resolve method even  (this.getActivity() or getParentActivity() or getCallingActivity()) gives the same result cannot apply

Answer (score 0):

Vasily Kabunov's Answer worked for me. I tried using a context variable but i didn't work. When I replaced  `Intent intent = new Intent(context, AddNodeActivity.class);`
with `Intent intent = new Intent(AllNodesActivity.this, AddNodeActivity.class);`
it worked.